# Java UDP server not consistent

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, udp

I'm not too familiar with UDP programming and Java so please excuse me if I come across a bit ignorant with my question.

I am testing UDP packets using my home network and I have a feeling that my AT&T router is blocking traffic between computers.

I've used these sample echo server/client java programs provided in:  [Working with UDP DatagramSockets in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-udp-datagramsockets-java/)

When I run the server and client programs locally in a single computer (my raspberry pi, my windows pc, or my ubuntu VM hosted by my windows pc), they work fine: I get the message sent from the client printed on the server side and echoed back. However, when I try to run a server in one computer (any of the three mentioned above) and a client on a different computer, I don't get any response from the server when the client sends a message (I.E. I don't think the messages are ever getting to the server).

For context, I've changed the "server address" that the client sends messages to by changing the code from the link provided from this:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

to this:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.228"); //ip address of one of my computers
```

A friend of mine tested the same thing at this home and he is able to talk accross computers without issue. Any clues to what may be happening at my place?

Thank you so much in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you, all we know is that "it doesn't work".

Comment: @BenAnderson Thanks for your answer. Not working means that when the client sends a message, the server never seems to receive it. The purpose of the client/server pair of programs from the link is for the client to send a string, the server prints the string and echoes it back. When "it doesn't work" the print on the server side never happens and the echo also never happens.

Comment: When your peer sends you a packet two things must happen: firstly it must know your IP address, that is to say the public address of your router and secondly your router must forward packets to the machine you're using.

Comment: @WKGuy, firstly make sure you can ping the IP address you are trying to reach. Secondly, you can run a python http-server on the port to check you can connect to it (if this doesn't work, it may be a firewall issue). After you've checked all the above, then revisit your server and client code to make sure it is correct